# If Else in python: returning to previous loops

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to append key's to other key's based on their name, but when i go through my if row.has_key(ft_test) statement, if the row doesn't have the value from ft_test, it doesn't append AND it goes on to the next if statement. I'd like for the code to return to the for ft in fieldMap.keys() line. Is there anyway to do this with an else statement or am i hopeless?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys 
import csv 
import glob 

fieldMap = {'zipcode':['Zip5', 'zip9','zipcode','ZIP','zip_code','zip','ZIPCODE'],
        'firstname':['firstname','FIRSTNAME'],and insert
        'lastname':['lastname','LASTNAME'],
        'cust_no':['cust_no','CUST_NO'], 
        'user_name':['user_name','USER_NAME'],# the keys here are ft
        'status':['status','STATUS'],# status must be filled
        'cancel_date':['cancel_date','CANCEL_DATE'],
        'reject_date':['REJECT_DATE','reject_date'],
        'streetaddr':['streetaddr','address2','STREETADDR','ADRESS2','ADDRESS','address'],
        'streetno':['streetno','STREETNO'],
        'streetnm':['streetnm','STREETNM'],
        'suffix':['suffix','SUFFIX'], 
        'city':['city','CITY'],
        'state':['state','STATE'],
        'phone_home':['phone_home','PHONE_HOME'],
        'email':['email','EMAIL']
        }


def readFile(fn,ofp):

    count = 0
    CSVreader = csv.DictReader(open(fn,'rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in CSVreader:
            count+= 1
            if count == 1:
                    hdrlist = []
                    for ft in fieldMap.keys():
                            hdrlen = len(hdrlist) 
                            for ft_test in fieldMap[ft]:
                                    if row.has_key(ft_test): 
                                            hdrlist.append(ft_test)   
                            if hdrlen != len(hdrlist)+1: 
                                    print "Cannot find a key for %s" % ft 
                                    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This code is very unreadable IMO...

Comment: Use `break` to get out of the inner loop

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc The perfect example of "too much comments kill the comments".

Comment: one suggestion: set your tabstop/spacing to 4 instead of 8.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `break` keyword:

```
hdrlen = len(hdrlist) # hdrlen equals the number of headers in header list
for ft_test in fieldMap[ft]:# ft_test = values of keys in field map
    if row.has_key(ft_test): # if a row has a key from the values from fieldMap # why does it stop after testing only one key??????????????
        hdrlist.append(ft_test)
        break
```

When the `if` case is `True`, it will `break` out of the inner `for-loop`.